# URL to have Language code and Country code both

Tags: sitecore-client, multilingual

The requirement is to have country code in the URL along with the Language code.

Its a Single site with multiple languages, have one site definition, currently am doing testing in local, production is deployed in azure PaaS environment. and its `Sitecore 10.1.2`

Please suggest me the best approach to have country code and language code both in URL.

I have set `languageEmbedding="always"` the Sitecore adds language code to URL, but our requirement is to include country code as well in the URL.

example: `sitename/zh-TW/TW/pagename`

In the above example `zh-TW` is language code and `TW` is country code.